# EAS Build: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children'

Tags: expo, eas

I'm struggling to debug the following error from eas build when attempting to submit to eas. My main problem is I can't see if there's anything more in the logs because the file path it claims the logs in doesn't exist (and just searching for the filename shows it doesn't exist).

So first question is where do I find the logs? And second question is, any ideas on how to fix the error below?

```
Running "npm install" in /Users/expo/workingdir/build directory

    [stderr] 

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')

[stderr] 


[stderr] 

npm ERR!

[stderr] 

A complete log of this run can be found in:

[stderr] 

npm

[stderr] 

ERR!     /Users/expo/.npm/_logs/2023-08-14T22_09_02_074Z-debug-0.log

npm install exited with non-zero code: 1
```